# How to Count number of fields using mysql PDO and OR expression?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Having trouble counting number of results to tally a field in mySQL table (php / mysqlPDO).

The challenge I am having is that the field called 'rotation' can have a number of values.  I would to add together all results in field 'rotation' which equal 29,30,31 or 32 for a specific user called "assignedRad".

Here is my code. Error is

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
$assignedRad=8; // this is the USER ID
// count vacation tally
$rotation=29;
$rotationoff=30;
$rotationvacay=31;
$rotationvacaytwo=32;                                       
$sql="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table WHERE (rotation = :rotation OR rotation = :rotationoff OR rotation = :rotationvacay OR rotation = :rotationvacaytwo AND assignedRad = :assignedRad)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotation);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotationoff);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotationvacay);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotationvacaytwo);                                       
$stmt->bindParam(':assignedRad', $assignedRad);                                     
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $number_of_rows;   // this value should be the SUM of the total number of times 'rotation' has an occurrence when it equals 29, 30, 31 or 32
```

The SELECT statement shows that the number of fields is the same as the number of vars.
What is the most code efficient way to query this?

Comment: You used the wrong names in the binding. `$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotationoff);` should presumably be `$stmt->bindParam(':rotationoff', $rotationoff);`, etc.

Comment: You also could simplify it a bit `rotation in(:rotation, :rotationoff, :rotationvacay, :rotationvacaytwo) AND assignedRad = :assignedRad`  that also might take care of the potential `or`/`and` conflict you may have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not using the correct parameter names in the bindParam statements. They have to match those using in the query.

And I think you missed a closing bracket after you set of OR's

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE (    rotation = :rotation 
                OR rotation = :rotationoff 
                OR rotation = :rotationvacay 
                OR rotation = :rotationvacaytwo
            )
           AND assignedRad = :assignedRad";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotation);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationoff', $rotationoff);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationvacay', $rotationvacay);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationvacaytwo', $rotationvacaytwo);                                       
$stmt->bindParam(':assignedRad', $assignedRad);
```

Or as @Chris85 suggested, change the query slightly to use an IN clause

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM my_table 
        WHERE rotation IN (:rotation,:rotationoff,:rotationvacay,:rotationvacaytwo)
           AND assignedRad = :assignedRad";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotation', $rotation);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationoff', $rotationoff);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationvacay', $rotationvacay);
$stmt->bindParam(':rotationvacaytwo', $rotationvacaytwo);                                       
$stmt->bindParam(':assignedRad', $assignedRad);
```